# How to install libgdx project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I'm using libgdx for year or more, but now I got new computer, installed win 8.1, eclipse luna and wanted to move my project there. I've downloaded installer from here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

... created project with it, but it didn't appear in eclipse. I tried to import the project (one by one and also parent dir) but it's not working. I've used "Imort existing project into workspace".

Eclipse says "no projects are found to import".

Everything worked well before - I've installed libgdx project at least twice, but now it's using some "gradle" management system and it's not working for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44), and then you can import the project using `File` | `Import...` | `Gradle Project`.

Once you selected the location, click on `Build Model`. After that you can import the project just like a regular eclipse project.

Comment: Thank you Gabor. That really helped and I managed to import the project. However not to run it. I really don't understand why those libgdx developers had to destroy something that was working perfectly, but that's another story...